# What happens precisely when hot deploying a node.js application on Openshift?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

From the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-OpenShift-User_Guide-Hot_Deploying_Applications.html) I could find, I don't understand what precisely happens when a `node.js` application is hot deployed in Openshift.

Are the following assumptions correct?

1. The existing `node.js` application is stopped.
2. A new `node.js` application with the new pushed code is started.
3. Whatever was in memory in the existing `node.js` application is not transferred to the new one.
4. If these applications use a database (in other cartridge), this database is not restarted. The existing application closes its connection, and the new application creates a new one.
5. Hence, hot deployments are not recommended if your need to run a database script required for your newly pushed `node.js` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to answer this question is to go to the [source](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs/bin/control#L222-L242).

The post_deploy control operation, used as part of the build lifecycle, (git commit), is what get's called.

Depending on how the cartridge is configured (if your using npm and if your using supervisor), the cartridge will behave differently. If NPM is used the cartridge restarts, if your not using supervisor, the cartridge restarts.  Its only if you are **NOT** using NPM and supervisor is running, does the hot deployment feature, work as explained in the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-OpenShift-User_Guide-Hot_Deploying_Applications.html).

> Hot deploying your application enables your changes to take effect without restarting the application cartridge, thus increasing deployment speed and minimizing application downtime.

Comment: Ok, since I use NPM, there will be a restart. And it makes total sense that it does. In my case, hot deploy would probably avoid a database restart.

Comment: The database is a separate cartridge, with its own control script, and operations that occur when a build is done. So it should operate independent of your web framework. IE a build (restart) to node.js does not restart your db cartridge. In fact build operations, on the application should not effect (a [mysql cartridge](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-mysql/bin/control#L256-L283) as this cartridge does not define a post_deploy operation).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find out a lot for documentation from some official source on hot deployment on openshift, but I dont see anything more than these [lines](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-OpenShift-User_Guide-Hot_Deploying_Applications.html) anywhere,

I don't say I am really answering your question but here is something about the hot deployment approach, everyone must read [this](http://romeda.org/blog/2010/01/hot-code-loading-in-nodejs.html)

It just creates a server which watches changes to your js files,
Now, any time you modify js, the code will notice and replace the local js with the new code. Any existing requests will continue to use the old code, while any new incoming requests will use the new code. All without shutting down the server, bouncing any requests, prematurely killing any requests, or even relying on an intelligent load balancer.

I guess openshift does the same thing when hot deployment marker is enabled(I m not sure and this may not be the case). Now in this case, coming back to your question:

> 1. The existing node.js application is stopped and a new node.js application with the new pushed code is started: **NO**
> 2. If these applications use a database (in other cartridge), this database is not restarted. The existing application closes its
>      connection, and the new application creates a new one: **YES**

Comment: We have to distinguish between node.js application and application cartridge. As far as I understand it now (from https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-modifying-applications.html#hot-deployment), a new node.js application is created with script execution, but the cartridge is not restarted. Meaning my assumptions are probably right.

Comment: restarting the application would still create a downtime right? so there must be no direct shut down and restart mechanism, So your assumption number 1 & 2 are probably wrong

Comment: With out looking at the code, I'm not 100% sure all of the statements here are correct. In general the idea behind hot deployments is to keep the server from restarting. However in order to do this your container needs to provide a mechanism by which to do this. With OpenShift it looks like the container to do that for a node.js application is supervisor. Thus making it a requirement for hot deployments to work.